# How to select a random object except one spesific one from a list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, random, tuples

I am designing an experiment with the Expyriment package. There is two boxes and I give them random colors but they must be different from each others. I use for loop and enumerate to loop through:

```
color = [(0, 76, 153), (204, 0, 0), (0, 153, 0), (255, 230, 0)]

for i, x in enumerate(color):
    print(color[i])
    print(random.choice(color.remove(color[i])))
```

2 problems emerged from here, the tuple I removed gone forever and I got a TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

I search for a way to temporarely remove an tuple for looping but cant find it.

Also, when I tried using pop `print(random.choice(color.pop(i)))`,
it didnt give me an error but it just prints int not tuple. Also, object that I pop is still gone forever.

Full code>

```
color = [(0, 76, 153), (204, 0, 0), (0, 153, 0), (255, 230, 0)]
letter = ('b', 'r', 'g', 'y')

for i, x in enumerate(color):
frame = stimuli.Canvas((600, 600))
sti = stimuli.TextLine(letter[i], text_bold=True, text_colour=misc.constants.C_WHITE,
                       text_size=100, text_font='calibri')

positions = (200, -200)
n = (0, 1)
ac = random.choice(n)  # randomize the place of true box

sti_squ_1 = stimuli.Rectangle((100, 100), colour=color[i], position=(positions[ac], -200))  # true box
sti_squ_2 = stimuli.Rectangle((100, 100), colour=color[random.choice(color.remove(color[i]))], position=(positions[1 - ac], -200))
```

Comment: Where are you using `x`?

Comment: "...'NoneType' has no len()". I don't see you using `len` in your code.

Comment: Why don't you remove the specific one you do not want to choose prior to entering the for loop?

Comment: I need to loop through other lists too so i use i, with x. should I post the whole thing?

Comment: Yes you should post enough code so that we can reproduce your problem with all of your requirements satisfied.

Comment: @rahlf23 because I need it later, i will use this loop like for 100 times

Comment: @Austin it is about the random package's source code i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new list inside of your for loop that excludes the current item for that iteration:

```
import random

color = [(0, 76, 153), (204, 0, 0), (0, 153, 0), (255, 230, 0)]

for i in color:
    test = [j for j in color if j!=i]
    print(random.choice(test))
```

Note that using `color.remove(color[i]))` (or `color.remove(x)`, which is equivalent in your OP) will return `None`. Also note, `remove` does not return anything. It modifies the existing list in-place. This is the reason you are receiving your `NoneType` error.

The code above outputs (for example):

```
(0, 153, 0)
(255, 230, 0)
(255, 230, 0)
(204, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to randomly select a number of items from a collection without selecting the same thing multiple times, that's known as random sampling without replacement. Python's random module has a function specifically for this called [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

```
import random

color = [(0, 76, 153), (204, 0, 0), (0, 153, 0), (255, 230, 0)]

places = [(200, -200), (-200, -200)]

stim_squares = []
for place, col in zip(random.sample(places, len(places)),
                      random.sample(color, len(places))):
    stim_squares.append(
        stimuli.Rectangle((100, 100), colour=col, 
                          position=place))
```

Comment: cant even thank you with an upvote bc of my "reputation" but thank you.
Btw, it is working but with an error, if a trial is red + yellow, it is always red + yellow, it is not shuffling properly.

Comment: That should only happen if you're repeating the same [seed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed)